# In Django, how do I get all the instances of a model that have other instances of a related model attached to it with a ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I am trying to write a query that retrieves all the categories that have at least one `post` attached to it. In other words, I want to 'exclude' any category that doesn't have any post.

These are my models for `Category` and `Post`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, default="")
```

This is the code I am using in my query, currently it fetches all the categories, even if no Post is 'attached' to it:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
```

What I want is something like this:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(
    #  Only ones that have at least one Post that has it's 'category' field set to it.
)
```

I've searched the docs and everywhere else, but I can't figure out a solution.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: `Post` model has a foreign key to `Topic` model and you are calling it `categories`. I am not sure I understand how this relationship is working with `Category` model.

Comment: @AKS Sorry for the confusion. I had replaced Topic with Category in the question, thought it would make it more clear what I was trying to achieve. I've fixed that now, so thanks.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(post__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This will get all the categories where `post` is not null. Since, one category could have multiple posts, you will get duplicate instances with same id. Take a `distinct` to remove duplicate categories.

Note, that `distinct(*fields)` is postgresql specific. If you are using a different database, just use `distinct()`.

Comment: I got the following error with that code:


NotImplementedError at /
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend.


Removing .distince('id') at the end got rid of the error, but it's getting duplicate instances as you had mentioned.

Comment: I see. Using `distinct` with a field is purely postgresql specific and it seems you are using a different database. You can use `distinct()` without any fields.

Comment: I am using SqlLite. Using distinct() fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Get all unique category ids by querying `Post` for distinct category and then filter Category by ids.

```
id_list = Post.objects.values_list('category_id').distinct()
catgories = Category.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```